# Galois field algorithm from C to Matlab

Tags: c, matlab, galois-field

I'm transcribing a C code for Matlab from a multiplication by 2 in the Gallois field, the problem is that my matlab code is not displaying the same value as the C code. Apparently everything is ok, I commented the code in matlab to identify the adaptations of the C code, below the codes.

C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  unsigned char value = 0xaa;
  signed char temp;
  // cast to signed value
  temp = (signed char) value;
  printf("\n%d",temp);
  // if MSB is 1, then this will signed extend and fill the temp variable with 1's
  temp = temp >> 7;
  printf("\n%d",temp);
  // AND with the reduction variable
  temp = temp & 0x1b;
  printf("\n%d",temp);
  // finally shift and reduce the value
  printf("\n%d",((value << 1)^temp));
}
```

Output:

```
-86
-1
27
335
```

MatLab:

```
hex = uint8(hex2dec('1B'));                     % define 0x1b
temp = uint8(hex2dec('AA'));                    % temp = (signed char) value;
disp(temp);
value = uint8(hex2dec('AA'));                   % unsigned char value = 0xaa
temp = bitsra(temp,7);                          % temp = temp >> 7;
disp(temp);
temp = bitand(temp,hex);                        % temp = temp and 0x1b  
disp(temp);
galois_value =  bitxor(bitsll(value,1),temp);   % ((value << 1)^temp)
disp(galois_value);                             % printf ("\n%u",...)
```

Output:

```
 170

    1

    1

   85
```

The C code works correctly, I'm printing `%d` in the C code to show the integer value of the varible because the cast in the beggining of the code.

Someone knows what is happening

Comment: Why do you think that `temp = uint8(hex2dec('AA'));` is equivalent to `temp = (signed char) value;`?

Comment: You need to look at where the computations begin to diverge on their own instead of making us do it for you.

Comment: Add a `printf` after every line in C and `disp` in MATLAB.

Comment: Because, I can't convert hex to int, only to double.

Comment: Even if I use double, the final value is different.

Comment: I mean why do you think `uint8` is the same as `signed char`?

Comment: I'm using `uint8` because the `bitand` and `bitxor` only accept values from the same type, if I cast to `int8` instead of `uint8` the code doesn't works.

Comment: When you provide a set of printouts for each line showing where the results begin to divege, an an analysis of why you think it is happening (in your question, not in the comments), I will answer it.

Comment: When I print the value of the variable `temp` in the C code, the value shown doesn't exist, I'm going to update the question to show you.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not saying to print `temp` every time. I'm saying to print the result of every line. In MATLAB too.

Comment: Perhaps you should first get the C code working with data types acceptable to Matlab.

Comment: If you have `uint8 value;`, you can copy the highest bit into all bits using `uint8_t temp = (value & 128) ? 255 : 0;` or even `uint8_t temp = (((unsigned int)(value & 128) << 9) - ((unsigned int)(value & 128) << 2)) >> 8;` Do not make assumptions about two's complement format.

Comment: Or, use `uint8_t temp = (value & 128) ? 0x1B : 0x00;` or perhaps even `uint8_t temp = ((unsigned int)(value & 128) * 54) >> 8;`

Comment: @MadPhysicist I've edited the post to show the value of the variables after every operation.

Comment: @NominalAnimal the C code is from a texas library to a MSP430 MCU, I can't change the C code, I need to adapt the matlab code to work like the C code from texas.

Comment: You need to add the output to the question, as well as an explanation of why the values come out differently when they do.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I've edited again with the output values.

Comment: In Matlab, you can calculate `temp` using `temp = uint8((bitand(value, 128) * 54) / 256);`. That way, `temp == 0x1B` if `value` has bit 7 set, otherwise `temp == 0`.

Comment: @NominalAnimal the output value gets `84` with this `temp` function, same as if I use all the variables as `int8`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
hex = uint8(hex2dec('1B')); 

temp = typecast(uint8(hex2dec('AA')), 'int8');
disp(temp);

temp = bitshift(temp,-7); 
disp(temp);

temp = bitand(typecast(temp,'uint8'),hex); 
disp(temp);

galois_value =  bitxor(bitshift(uint16(hex2dec('AA')),1),uint16(temp));   
disp(galois_value);
```

Comment: Like I said before, I didn't create the C code, It's from Texas Company, It's from a library of AES criptography used in MSP430 series MCU, should I assume that when I implement the rest of the code the encryption will work? Because the output value of the original texas function is different, what was to be 335 is now being 85.

Comment: @Mutante, sorry. I missed that you are converting from C to Matlab. I've updated my post. Take a look again please.

Comment: The `typecast` function was very useful, I didn't know of its existence, thanks @wyc!